# T-SQL: SUSER_SNAME vs SUSER_NAME?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The MSDN documentation says for [SUSER_SNAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174427.aspx) function:

> Returns the login identification name from a user's security identification number (SID).

More over, it says for the [SUSER_NAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187934.aspx) function:

> Returns the login identification name of the user.

Nonetheless, when I execute the following SQL statements I get **the same result**:

```
SELECT SUSER_NAME();
SELECT SUSER_SNAME();
```

So, what are differences, and which one shall I use? Is there a situation I should use one rather that the other?

Please advice,

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 34):

If you call the function without an argument they will both return the same value. But they do take different arguments:

- SUSER_SNAME() takes the `varbinary(85) SID` of a login as argument
- SUSER_NAME() takes the `integer principal_id` of a login

You can verify this like:

```
select  suser_name(principal_id)
,       suser_name(sid)
,       suser_sname(principal_id)
,       suser_sname(sid)
from    sys.server_principals 
where   name = suser_name()
```

Only the first and last column will return non-null values.

Comment: I executed the statement you provided, and only the third column was null, it seems like `SUSER_NAME` accepts both `principal_id` and `sid`. By the way I am using SQL Server 2012 if that matters.

Comment: @MohammedA.Fadil: Strange, I'm using 2012 too, and column two and three are `null`.  There might be a corner case where `cast(sid as int)` equals a `principal_id`, but that is highly unlikely

Comment: @MohammedA.Fadil: Were you logged in as sa when you saw that result? I am seeing principal_id = sid for the built-in server principals.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2012 SP1 and I have the same result ask Andomar described.

Comment: I think I figured out why Mohammed saw less NULLs. Try this query: `select  sid,principal_id, CONVERT(int,sid) SidConverted
,  suser_name(principal_id) NamePid
,       suser_name(sid) NameSid
,       suser_sname(principal_id) SnamePid
,       suser_sname(sid) SnameSid
from    sys.server_principals` . Whenever principal_id and SidConverted are equal, NameSid will have a value. I guess when using `suser_name(sid)`, the sid is implicitely converted to a int.

Answer (score 1):

SUSER_NAME() will return the name associated with an sid that exists in sys.server_principals.  The sid must exist in sys.server_principals.

SUSER_SNAME() can do that but also can return the sid of a login if the login is a member of an active directory group

So if you have [CONTOSO\MyGroup] in Active Directory and that group has one user [CONTOSO\MyUser]

And you add that group to SQL Server:
CREATE LOGIN [CONTOSO\MyGroup] FROM WINDOWS;

SELECT SUSER_ID('CONTOSO\MyUser'), SUSER_SID('CONTOSO\MyUser')

will give you
NULL, CONTOSO\MyUser 
because CONTOSO\MyUser is not in sys.server_principals but is in A/D